# What kind of calculations would I need that takes a while for a pc to complete but not as long for several pcs?

Tags: c#, rpc, distributed

I'm working with Unity and RPC calls. Very basic stuff as my ability would be low atm. At the moment I have a client and server. When the client connects to the server, the user on the server can hit a button (what is 2+2) and the client gets the answer to it and sends it back. The client doesn't calculate it, it has the answer and sends it back over. I am going to attempt the working out part now. However later on I would like to be able to show that 2 pcs are greater than one. I would like to have  two calculations or something that would take one pc a long time to work out and then split those so that there is one calculation to one pc.

Am I thinking about this all wrong? in that its not going to be a long sum or anything like that?
What kind of calculation should I be using?

The purpose of this is for a project. I am looking at distributed processing (hence the whole 2 calculations takes too long on one machine so send one to another to save time), when I get the basics down I will be moving on to applying this to a game.

Comment: Anything that can be map reduced?

Answer (score 0):

Raytacing is a good bet as it is embarassingly parallelizable.

You could raytrace your image in 1 go, but also raytrace half of the image on each computer, that would be easy to split to any number of computers up to pixels in resolution = number of computers

Comment: Hey! Now looking at ray tracing, is it easy enough to divide up the image to be able to send it to the other pc? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You don't divide the image, you send the same data to all pc (the scene) and tell them to render a certain bunch of pixels (say you're rendering a 1000x800, you could say each of them rnders 200X800 if you have 5 for example, then you get all the pixel back from each and make the final image from that)

Comment: Ahh I get ya now! Thanks! Going to keep this open for other ideas!

Comment: Google up "embarassingly parallelizable" if you want more ideas, some problems like ray tracing are embarassingly parallelizable as no operation on 1 item (a ray) needs information about operation on another item (another ray), so you can launch countless such operations in parallel with barely any disadvantages